# Perl - Sending HTML message via Amazon SES

Tags: html, perl, email, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Trying to send HTML message via Amazon SES, mail is getting delivered, but its not showing content like an HTML page but just plain text.

This is the code:

```pl
use Net::AWS::SES;
my $htmlBody = qq~<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='http://example.com/css/animatedButton.css'>
<style>
html{
overflow:hidden;
}
                        @import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Ubuntu:400,700);
                        body {
                                /* IE10 Consumer Preview */
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e9f0f2 100%);

/* Mozilla Firefox */
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e9f0f2 100%);

/* Opera */
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e9f0f2 100%);

/* Webkit (Safari/Chrome 10) */
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, color-stop(0, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #e9f0f2));

/* Webkit (Chrome 11+) */
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #ffffff 0%, #e9f0f2 100%);

/* W3C Markup, IE10 Release Preview */
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #ffffff 0%, #e9f0f2 100%);

                                #background: #3F53C4 no-repeat center top;
                                -webkit-background-size: cover;
                                -moz-background-size: cover;
                                background-size: cover;
                        }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class=\"wrapper\">
        <div style=\"text-align: right; margin-top:2px; margin-right:2px;\"><img src=\"http://trackmyphones.com/ct/images/logos/celltracker.png\" width=\"50\" height=\"50\"/></div>
<p>
<div style=\"text-align: center; font-weight: bold;\">This is test msg from AWS SES</div>
</p>
<div style=\"text-align: left; margin-left:5%;margin-right: 5%; margin-bottom:2%; padding-left:2%; padding-right:2%; padding-top:2%; padding-bottom: 2%; background-color:#fae3e3;\">
<p>
This is test body
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
~;

my $ses = Net::AWS::SES->new(access_key => '...', secret_key => '...');

    my $r = $ses->send(
        From    => 'to@example.com',
        To      => 'recepient@gmail.com',
        Subject => 'Hello World from SES',
        Body_html    => "$htmlBody",
    );

 unless ( $r->is_success ) {
        die "Could not deliver the message: " . $r->error_message;
    }

 printf("Sent successfully. MessageID: %s\n", $r->message_id);
```

The above code returns success but mail received will not have the background color as set in the html.

The same html mail works perfectly when sent via sendmail.

Can anyone help me on what's missing?

EDIT:

Used the below MIME Type as well:

```
my $msg = MIME::Entity->build(
        From    => 'to@example.com',
        To      => 'from@gmail.com',
        Subject => 'New Hello World from SES',
        Data    => ' ',
        Type    => 'text/html'
    );

    $msg->attach(
        Data     => "$mailContent",
        Type     => 'text/html'
    );
```

The above also shows text and not html, however if i change Data to point to a file it shows properly but then i will have to write all mail to a file and then send mail to SES:

```
 $msg->attach(
        Path     => File::Spec->catfile(  'htmlContentMail.html' ),
        Type     => 'text/html'
    );
```

Comment: Try generating a MIME object?

Comment: Compare the source of a successful email and an unsuccessful one.